# AWS Config Resource inventory not updating

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created a service linked role config, and turned on the config recorder. Then created an AWS managed rule - "`s3-bucket-server-side-encryption-enabled`".

There are 5 buckets in the region, some of them have bucket policies attached, but there is no explicit deny. 4 of them are encrypted, and one is not - I created it for testing the rule. Whenever I run the rule, it only detects 2 buckets out of 5, and say that rule is compliant, while it is not. If I check the resource inventory, under S3 buckets, it only shows two. But the configuration history shows it was successfully delivered today.

I waited few days to see if it gets updated, but it is not. In cloudtrail, I can only see that two events called "`PutEvaluations`" which checks the two buckets. What could be the reason ? and how can I troubleshoot it ?

Answer (score 1):

In case if anyone is stuck here, my issue was a service control policy that blocks access to some regions. Since config is a global resource, I needed to whitelist config to be able to run in all regions.

Comment: I find SCPs super useful, but they also cause problems that can be difficult to diagnose. Config (also related services Guard Duty, Security hub, and CloudTrail) have to be set up / configured in every region, so a region blocking SCP will prevent them working. Thanks for providing an answer :)